# Backbone.js model handling when urlroot returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am relatively a newbie to **backbone.js** and am working on a sample project with backbone frontend and backend based on **node.js**. I have two entities: `User` and `Bank` in the backend and backbone.js models corresponding to these two models with same names. `User` and and `Bank` have *one-to-one* relation.

The urlroot for the bank model is `/bank` and that corresponding too user is `/user`. Now the problem. A user may or may not have a bank entity associated with him. So when a user having a bank account is logged in the backbone model loads the bank corresponding to the logged in user.

How will I handle the backbone.js model for bank if the active user does not have a bank associated with him ? Currently I am returning null if a user does not have a bank associated with him. I feel that this is not the right approach. Any help on this regard is appreciated.

The code corresponding to `/bank` route is

```
app.get("/bank/:id?", function(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) {
    return JsonRenderer.error(null, res, 401, false);
  }
  return Bank.findById(req.user.id, function(err, bank) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    if (bank) {
      return res.json(JsonRenderer.user(bank));
    }
    if (!bank) {
        return JsonRenderer.error('No User', res, 200, false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `null` seems fine as long as you handle it appropriately in the front-end.

Comment: If I send null to the Backbone.js model from the backend, the defaults that I specify in the Backbone.js model get assigned to the attributes of the Model. I hope this is the right way of handling null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if it does what you want then it's okay. But I think it's kind of an interesting question about semantics and how the semantics shape the logic so I'll throw in my answer and see if someone has a better way of thinking about this. I want to learn something too.

From what I read in your description I think about this problem a little differently. Namely, your usage of null and how it's handled as a response.

In my mind, a person that hasn't entered a bank account in the database would be `undefined`. Nothing has been defined. This would be someone who like, just created an account but hasn't gotten to that part yet. A person who has explicitly said that they don't have a bank account might be `null`, an object that sort of represents "nothing". Some people would not want to mix these two in their DB column. There is a lot of hubbub about the difference and apparently this is a very JS thing that drives non-JS programmers rabid. ;-)

So given that, I think there is some kind of missing step here which is to know before you make a request for a resource (the bank) whether you should even bother to request it or not. For example, if `User` and `Bank` are one to one, you might consider adding some reference to the Bank via id or null or undefined in the `User` object. This way, when you get the User you could see whether you need to lazily load the bank information if there is one associated with it. If null (or undefined), you don't need to. If it has a BankID like, `user.get('bankID');` then you can create an empty model with `model.id = bankID` and then `.fetch()`. Thus you only create a Bank model if you need one. Now your `success` `error` callback doesn't have to deal with two issues - figuring out if Bank exists, and figuring out about the User. Which is kind of RESTful, since a URL in pure form is about a resource we want. We might want to know if we want the resource before asking for it. Sounds like you're creating a Bank model, then fetching for it but not knowing whether there is one. So you end up with a default bank. Which might not be bad. It might just be an empty representation of a bank. In which case, maybe another way of thinking about it is that everyone DOES have a Bank, just that some Bank information has been filled out and others have not. Like, I might not fill out my profile but I probably still have a profile object created for me when I register. :-)

There is another way to think about this too. Which is, maybe Banks should have some sort of pointer to the User. Parse.com which uses an old fork of Backbone uses this method. Basically I might have something like `Bank.user` pointing to the `User` model/object. So on the client side, my user is loaded, then I make a query for a Bank object that includes a pointer to the User I want. This query in Parse just returns undefined if it can't find anything but will return the bank if it matches the query based on the user.

Anyway, I thought it was an interesting question.